# Can't change the color of buttons in Kotlin (Android Studio)

Tags: xml, android-studio, kotlin

I am new to Android programming. I am trying to change the background color of buttons.

The background color of the buttons is pink. I changed the color in XML but the color doesn't change. Someone said create a shape in XML but I did not understand.

[image: can't change the color of buttons]

Comment: Is it only like this in the layout inspector? or in the emulator you have the same problem? if it look ok in the emulator, cleaning the project will fix the layout inspector.

Comment: If you set the background to a solid color, there will be no visual change when the button is tapped, so it will look terrible. Use `backgroundTint` instead of `background`.